# How do I retrieve the data within this URL when running the program from my local machine?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, local-storage

I am testing a website and trying to run data within the URL on my website via my local machine, but its not working.

```
function getQuotes() {
  return $.ajax({
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    },
    url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json',
    success: function(jsonQuotes) {
      if (typeof jsonQuotes === 'string') {
        quotesData = JSON.parse(jsonQuotes);
        console.log('quotesData');
        console.log(quotesData);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The quote box should be filled with the JSON data when I run the site from my IDE.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/punowixode/1/edit?html,js,console — I can't reproduce the problem

Answer (score -1):

depending on the version of jQuery you are using, you can simply use `$.getJSON()`

Here is an example :

```js
(function() {

  var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json";

  $.getJSON( url)
    .done(function( data ) {
      // Ensure data.quotes is an array
      if(Array.isArray(data.quotes)) {
        // Append each quote in the quote box
        $.each( data.quotes, function(i, item) {
          var quoteText = item.quote + " (" + item.author + ")";
          $("#quotesBox").append("<blockquote>" + quoteText + "</blockquote>");
        });
      }      
    });

})();
```

```css
blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;  
  font-style: italic;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left: 5px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="quotesBox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code *could* be rewritten like that, but how does it solve the problem? As far as I can tell by testing the code, there isn't a problem at all.

Comment: You're right @Quentin, I refactored my code sample to show how to append each quote as a child element of a DOM element with a `quotesBox` id.